# Posting data in PHP Curl

Tags: php, post, file-upload, curl, zoho

I am trying to post the content in a file as a param using PHP CURL.

The data gets posted but Zoho opens a blank document instead of the one I'm trying to open.

I believe its because I am providing invalid input the `$post_data['content']` variable.

`$post_data['content']  = "@/c:/xampp/htdocs/site/a.doc";`

Zoho opens a blank document when the content received is empty according to what it says in the ZOHO API.

My code is given below for reference.
    <

```
?php   
        $post_data['content']  = "@/c:/xampp/htdocs/site/a.doc";
        $post_data['apikey']   = '[MY API KEY IS HERE]';
        $post_data['output']   = 'url';
        $post_data['filename'] = "a.doc";
        $post_data['id']       = '12345678';
        $post_data['format']   = "doc";
        $post_data['saveurl']  = 'https://localhost/researchPortal/tmp/save.php';
        $post_data['agentname'] = 'ZRemoteAgent';
        $post_data['mode']   = "normaledit";

        foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value)
        {
            $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
        }

        $post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);



    //create cURL connection
$curl_connection =  curl_init('https://exportwriter.zoho.com/remotedoc.im');

//set options
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,  "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

//set data to be posted
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

//perform our request
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);

                echo $result;

//close the connection
curl_close($curl_connection);

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be change

`curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);`

to

`curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);`

Im guessing converting it into a string is making curl not upload the file with the magic @
http://dtbaker.com.au/random-bits/uploading-a-file-using-curl-in-php.html

Comment: Well I tried it and I got a server error on zoho's end
`com.adventnet.iam.security.IAMSecurityException: XSS_DETECTED`
I think I have to put the path of the document, because zoho uploads the file.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me, I finally managed to get it working. I used an array $fields = array(); instead of $post_data